# LWC: Can I have an expression and a string as a class combination?

Tags: lightning-web-components, class, css

I have a div and I want to assign one css class statically and one dynamically.

Something like this:

```
<div class="my-class + {dynamicClass}"></div>
```

However that is not working and I am not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can only use getters for specifying a value, such as:

```
<div class={classes}>
```

...

```
get classes() {
  return `my-class ${this.dynamicClass}`;
}
```

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_public).

Answer (score -1):

In aura component you can do it but not in LWC.

Here is how you can do it in aura, Make an aura attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="currentStep" type="string" default="slds-is-active"/>
```

assign `currentStep` attribute value in JS controller and use like this in component.

```
<div class="{! 'slds-progress__item' + ' ' + (v.currentStep)}">
```

Or you can also assign class dynamically with condition like this using aura expression.

```
<div class="{! 'slds-progress__item' + ' ' + (v.currentStep == 'slds-is-active' ? 'slds-is-completed' : '')}">
```

For more on how to use expressions follow this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_overview.htm).

Comment: <aura:attribute/> is part of the aura framework and are not supported in LWC. My question was specifically for Lightning Web Components.

Comment: Just edited my answer and make it specific to aura component.